# Trouble with using DXA 1.6 in SDL Web 8

Tags: web8, dxa

I have imported DXA 1.6 into SDL Web8 and published [Home] SG under [400 Example Site].
I checked contents were published to Broker DB.
When I access my website by Url "http://ServerIP:8085/", the page showed `No matching Localization found for URL 'http://ServerIP:8085/'`.  (The "defaultdocument" in web.config of my site is set to "index.html")
If I access my website by Url "http://ServerIP:8085/index.html", the page showed without js & css. Could not get css/js assets http://ServerIP:8085/system/v1.6/assets/css/main.css.
I found that css & js is under `E:\SDL\DXAStaging\BinaryData\13063\system\assets`, "E:\SDL\DXAStaging" is my site's physical path.
Page without design seems like the same situation with [Problem with DXA 1.4 Assets path with version no is not accessible](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/problem-with-dxa-1-4-assets-path-with-version-no-is-not-accessible).

Below is my ttm settings. (discovery service with 8092 port is used for DXA. 8082 is for my existing sites)
Is it correct that map "400 Example Site"(tcm:0-13063-1) with WebApplication leaving Relative Url "/"? This mapping was created after running cms-import.ps1.
[image]
[image]

Below is cd-core.log. Does this error have relation with mapping?

```
2016-12-06 10:44:53,969 ERROR ODataFunctionProcessorImpl - Unexpected exception when executing a function.
com.sdl.odata.api.processor.datasource.ODataEntityNotFoundException: Can't resolve publication from given URL: http://ServerIP:8085/
    at com.sdl.web.content.datalayer.dynamic.DynamicContentProvider.getPublicationMappingFromUrl(DynamicContentProvider.java:42) ~[content-common-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:42) ~[content-common-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:20) ~[content-common-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36) ~[content-common-8.1.0-1233.jar:8.1.0-1233]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.doFunction(ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.java:63) ~[odata_processor-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:36) [odata_service-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29) [odata_service-2.0.0-1218.jar:2.0.0-1218]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

snippet of cd_adf.log

```
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 INFO  AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Requested by IP: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_5965543f-23b8-4259-808c-5c4bd8ed4e88
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, value=tridion_1ad9b239-0538-46af-9001-c6d65539074c
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:attributes, value={}
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Processing cookie claims.
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding is enabled: true
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding for account is set to: null
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - IP address is in the white list: false
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding for current request is allowed: false
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onSessionStart event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running session start Claim Processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestStart event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request start claim processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.JavaClaimStore@328576ca, thread: ODataAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-52
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - doFilter: contextPath=, sessionId=864FDF7ABF9E4D12C0D81B88B048A3DA
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Creating new ClaimStore for session: 864FDF7ABF9E4D12C0D81B88B048A3DA
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:response:cookie:generation, value=true
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.JavaClaimStore@6a8cc03, thread: http-nio-8093-exec-10
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:uri, value=/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://ServerIP:8085/media/bulls-eye_tcm13063-37537_w1024_h633_n.JPG')
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:full_url, value=http://localhost:8093/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://ServerIP:8085/media/bulls-eye_tcm13063-37537_w1024_h633_n.JPG')
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:headers, value={authorization=[Ljava.lang.String;@3de7f15c, host=[Ljava.lang.String;@629b4871, odata-maxversion=[Ljava.lang.String;@6d736577, accept=[Ljava.lang.String;@2d7b740e, accept-charset=[Ljava.lang.String;@2f941dec, user-agent=[Ljava.lang.String;@17f400af}
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:parameters, value={CONTENT_LENGTH=[Ljava.lang.String;@615a97fb, QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@17f744da, CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@180340b5, PATH_INFO=[Ljava.lang.String;@2fc5da62}
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, value={SERVER_PORT=8093, REMOTE_HOST=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat-docbase.7014025966174846702.8093\, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, SCRIPT_NAME=/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http:/ServerIP:8085/media/bulls-eye_tcm13063-37537_w1024_h633_n.JPG'), REMOTE_ADDR=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SECURE=false, PATH_TRANSLATED=null, SERVER_NAME=localhost, AUTH_TYPE=null, REMOTE_USER=null}
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies, value={}
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.JavaClaimStore@669d8d97, thread: ODataAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-53
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 INFO  AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Requested by IP: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:id, value=tridion_9fe0b4e6-49eb-4062-b4f1-884c92bd19c4
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:tracking:id, value=tridion_bd5dbe04-0385-43d8-a6d3-ce930db18cec
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:session:attributes, value={}
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Processing cookie claims.
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding is enabled: true
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding for account is set to: null
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - IP address is in the white list: false
2016-12-09 15:43:47,570 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Cookie forwarding for current request is allowed: false
2016-12-09 15:43:47,586 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onSessionStart event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,586 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running session start Claim Processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,586 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestStart event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,586 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request start claim processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,601 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestEnd event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,601 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request end Claim Processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,601 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - remove: uri=taf:session:preview:preview_session
2016-12-09 15:43:47,601 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: http-nio-8093-exec-7
2016-12-09 15:43:47,601 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: com.tridion.ambientdata.claimstore.JavaClaimStore@6a8cc03, thread: ODataAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-57
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestEnd event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request end Claim Processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - remove: uri=taf:session:preview:preview_session
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: http-nio-8093-exec-9
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestEnd event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request end Claim Processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - remove: uri=taf:session:preview:preview_session
2016-12-09 15:43:47,633 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: http-nio-8093-exec-8
2016-12-09 15:43:47,664 DEBUG AmbientDataServletFilter - Dispatching onRequestEnd event
2016-12-09 15:43:47,664 DEBUG ServerEngine - Running request end Claim Processor class com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor
2016-12-09 15:43:47,664 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - remove: uri=taf:session:preview:preview_session
2016-12-09 15:43:47,664 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: http-nio-8093-exec-10
```

snippet of cd_discovery.log

```
2016-12-09 14:47:34,716 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 14:47:34,716 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 14:47:34,747 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 14:47:34,747 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 14:51:31,990 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 14:51:32,006 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 14:51:34,771 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 14:51:34,771 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 14:51:34,787 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 14:51:34,787 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 15:43:43,695 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 15:43:43,695 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 15:43:45,961 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 15:43:45,961 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-12-09 15:43:45,976 INFO  CachingConfigurationProvider - Configuration Repository not configured.
2016-12-09 15:43:45,976 WARN  HybridConfigurationProvider - OData service not configured in 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
```

snippet of cd_preview.log

```
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,200 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,216 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,232 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,310 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByProperty' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,325 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
2016-12-09 16:05:27,341 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByPageURL' while not in session.
```

Do I need to configure ADF or something else?

Comment: What version string is mentioned in `E:\SDL\DXAStaging\BinaryData\13063\version.json`?

Comment: {"version":"v1.6"}

Comment: That confirms the HTML design is published, so the URL  http://ServerIP:8085/system/v1.6/assets/css/main.css should work, if it doesn't but http://ServerIP:8085/index.html does, I'd say there might have gone something unexpected wrong, and you could consider dropping the current website and reinstalling it. Or as I mentioned in the other question, try connecting it to a DXA app on Azure, so you can confirm your CIS setup is correct and working.

Comment: I'm also confused that why ServerIP:8085 didn't display page but ServerIP:8085/index.html dose. Is there something wrong with the setting in ttm?

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16114/error-while-accessing-dxa-1-6-website . Am I correct? Did you already contact SDL Support?

Comment: Not yet. I'll have my last try...

Comment: Is your discovery URL correct in web.config?

Comment: can you try adding some host port 80. myapp.myhost.com and try if same issue exists.

Comment: I checked the discovery service URL is correct in web.config.

Comment: I tried other port and it worked fine. I'm wondering if dynamic_conf.xml or ambient_conf.xml of preview service should be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cd_discovery.log` reveals an issue. Does that come from your Content Service?

Note that the (Session-enabled) Content Service has a reference to the Discovery Service in its configuration (`cd_storage_conf.xml`). You have to ensure that reference points to the Discovery Service of the CD Environment where the Content Service belongs to (if you have cloned the CD Environment from another, it may be pointing to the wrong Discovery Service).

Another problem you might have (since you seem to be having some "aliasing" issues between your CD Environments) is that the Capabilities registered in the Discovery Service of your 2nd CD Environment are referencing the microservices from the 1st CD Environment.

**UPDATE**

The reference to Discovery Service in the `cd_storage_conf.xml` of the (Session-enabled) Content Service looks as follows:

```
<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"
    ConnectionTimeout="10000"
    CacheEnabled="true"
    CacheExpirationDuration="600"
    ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
    ClientId="cduser"
    ClientSecret="encrypted:o/cgCBwmULeOyUZghFaKJA=="> <!-- ClientSecret="CDUserP@ssw0rd" -->

</ConfigRepository>
```

Comment: Hi Rick. Could you tell me some details about the reference to discovery service in Content Service. Actually, I used the same install module for those roles of two environments, but I changed the port number, service name, and "Depends on" arguments in each installService.ps1. For example, $serverPort="--server.port=8093", $name="DXASDLWebSessionPreviewService", $arguments += "++DependsOn=DXASDLWebDiscoveryService" for my Content service of DXA. I didn't find information in cd_storage_conf.xml of Content Service which is referring to Discovery Service.

Comment: Rick, I found this existed in content's cd_storage_conf.xml, but didn't exist in session-enabled content service's cd_storage_conf.xml. I added this into session-enabled content service's cd_storage_conf.xml and all the images, js & css appeared! Amazing, even though I'm not clear about why this solved.

Comment: Good to hear your issue is finally resolved.